# Standard user in computer

Tags: group-policy

I have 100 computers that connect to domain. In every computer the domain users defines as administrator in local computer.
I want that all users in computers that assign to domain, will be standard user not administrator. 
How can I do it in group policy? Another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "skip=1" %%a in ('wmic UserAccount get Name') do (
    if not "%%a"==""  (
                net localgroup Users "%%a" /add
                net localgroup Administrators "%%a" /delete             
    )
)
```

Comment: Is this the answer to your question? If so, accept it as the answer. Otherwise, update your original question with this information. You can find more information on how to ask questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).